# EXCEL FORMULA: Interpolate between 2 unknown points

Tags: excel, excel-formula

an avid excel user trying to lose weight. I have put my goal at the end and projected how much I should be losing each day, however I only want to weigh myself every so often 1-5 days. The issue this bring is i want to be able to write a formula that will give an average expected.
For example, I want a formula I can just copy between the cells which aren't entered i.e.

```
Day, Weight
1, 100
2,
3, 98
```

So then copying an excel formula would give `= 100-(100-98)/2 = 99`

But lets take a 5 day scenario:

Input:

```
Day, Weight
1, 100
2, 
3, 
4,
5, 20
```

This creates an issue as

```
Day 2 = Day 1 - (Day 1 - Day 3)/2
Day 3 = Day 2 - (Day 2 - Day 4)/2
Day 4 = Day 3 - (Day 3 - Day 5)/2
```

However, this then creates dependent formulas on one another, I don't really want to change the cells in the formula each day. Do you have an idea how I can get around this?

Comment: Have you looked up linear interpolation, I'm sure there are many examples online. You don't need to calculate each day dependent on the previous.

Comment: I tried but everything I looked at seemed very complicated using index match ect